# Auto fill Facebook login form

Tags: c#, winforms, webbrowser-control, facebook-c#-sdk

I'm new to facebook SDK 6.0.10.0 for C#/Windows Form

I'm truing to find a solution to fill automatically the username and password field from login page in my WebBrowser Component. 
Storing the token is not a solution, in my case I test the client application with 5 different account, and I'm spending too much time on this.

This is my HTMLDocument generated from my WebBrowser control: http://pastebin.com/3Xy49vLG

How can I automate the work and not lose much time in testing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My reply doesn't use Facebook SDK, it just uses a System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser control with loaded http://facebook.com web page having the following login html controls in its top right corner:

[image]

```
    public void LoginToFaceBook(System.Windows.Forms.HtmlDocument doc, string email, string password)
    {
        //<input name="email" tabindex="1" class="inputtext" id="email" type="text" value="">
        doc.GetElementById("email").SetAttribute("value", email);
        //<input name="pass" tabindex="2" class="inputtext" id="pass" type="password">
        doc.GetElementById("pass").SetAttribute("value", password);
        //<input tabindex="4" id="u_0_n" type="submit" value="Log In">
        doc.GetElementById("u_0_n").InvokeMember("click");
    }

    /// <remarks>Should be logged-in to call this method</remarks>
    public void LogOutFromFaceBook(System.Windows.Forms.HtmlDocument doc)
    {
        // <input class="uiLinkButtonInput" type="submit" value="Log Out" />
        (from tag in doc.GetElementsByTagName("input").OfType<System.Windows.Forms.HtmlElement>()
         where tag.GetAttribute("className") == "uiLinkButtonInput" &&
                       tag.GetAttribute("type") == "submit" &&
                       tag.GetAttribute("value") == "Log Out"
                 select tag).First().InvokeMember("click");           
    }
```